# Map PassthroughSubject<[Int], Never> to AnyPublisher<Int, Never>

Tags: swift, combine

I want to achieve the opposite of the collect operator. Instead of collecting 10 items and then getting a publisher with array type, I want to get a subject with array type and have the publisher get each array element one by one.

So I could get my intended output by doing this:

```
let subject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()

let sub = subject.sink(receiveValue: {
    print($0)
})

for val in 1...100 {
    subject.send(val)
}
```

I want it to work like this, that the subject gets an array, and then add another operator to emit the values from the array one by one, like the opposite of the `collect` operator:

```
let subject = PassthroughSubject<[Int], Never>()

let sub = subject.sink(receiveValue: {
    print($0)
})

subject.send(Array(1...100))
```

The issue is that the second implementation prints the whole array as it just gets it as a value. I want to add a stage in the stream, a little like collect works but the opposite, to manipulate the stream that it will emit the values from the array one by one.

Is there any operator to achieve that?

Comment: `Array(1...100).publisher`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using `Sequence`:

```
let sub = Publishers
.Sequence(sequence: Array(1...100))
.sink(receiveValue: { print($0) })
.store(in: &subscriptions)
```